# Жизнь параметров в JS функции(конструктор)

Tags: javascript

```
function Foo(strParm1, intParam2){
  var param1 = strParm1; 
  var param2 = intParm2;
  this.GetParam1 = function(){ return param1; } 
  this.GetParam2 = function(){ return param2; } 
}
```

Вот такой вопрос, стоит ли создавать private members param1 и param2 как показано выше или можно сделать так:

```
function Foo(strParm1, intParam2){
  this.GetParam1 = function(){ return strParm1; } 
  this.GetParam2 = function(){ return intParam2; } 
}
```

какова жизнь параметров strParm1, intParam2 ???
спасибо!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Стоит или нет решает программист, жизнь параметров зависит от того "насколько важен" объект порожденный конструктором. Естественно если объект нигде больше не используется и использоваться не может с ним может расправится сборщик мусора(и то - не факт что он это сделает), но если он уже не нужен и думать об этом не стоит.

У второго способа есть 1 большой недостаток - методы getParam1 и getParam2 для каждого порожденного объекта копируются(читай "разные"), собственно это и есть цена приватности в javascript, конечно если речь идет, например, о синглтоне - в использовании такого подхода этих недостатков попросту не будет.

Лично я советую использовать такой подход только тогда когда это действительно необходимо.
В общем случае намного целесообразнее использовать прототипы. (как раз таки во избежание копирования)

Для обеспечения "псевдо-приватности" обычно используют примерно следующий подход:

```
function Foo(a,b){
     this._a = a;
     this._b = b;
}
Foo.prototype.getA = function() {
     return this._a;
}
Foo.prototype.getB = function() {
     return this._b;
}
```

Comment: как мне использовать prototype если  param1 и  param2 private?
private - они нужны ток для чтения.

Comment: в том то и загвоздка что **истинную приватность** можно обеспечить только копированием функций для каждого объекта локально.

Comment: ок вот если я сделаю задачу представленную в вопросе вторым вариантом то это будет эквивалент первого варианта. а параметры если уничтожаются по мере их использования, получается в гетерах они используются и будут жить пока живёт объект верно?

Comment: Верно, но при использовании прототипа - мы имеем общие геттеры и сеттеры для всех объектов, во втором примере - для **каждого объекта** создаются **свои геттеры и сеттеры**, но тогда мы обеспечиваем истинную приватность
****
Другой возможности реализовать истинную приватность в javascript нет

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае - создавать что-то дополнительно - бессмысленно...

Параметры функции ( а это обычные локальные переменные ) - живут вечно ( пока контекст не удалят, а в вашей ситуации - контекст = объект )

Приватные поля, имхо, в JS - не существуют...

Comment: Так и есть... Да же при создании "приватных" полей на самом деле просто создаються разные функции, но не приватные поля =)